# How to use js.erb and a html.erb partial in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, partials

I have a list of movies, on a page preceded by the list of categories. Initially the list of movies will have movies from all categories. But when user clicks one category then I would like the list to be replaced with movies only from the selected category.

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <tr><td><%= link_to category, '/movies/show_category', :category => category, :remote => true%></td></tr>
<% end %>

<div id="#movies_list">
<% @movies.each do |movie| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= movie.title %></td>
    <td><%= movie.category %> </td>
    <td><%= movie.rating %></td>

    <% if !current_user.nil? %>
      <% if movie.user.email == current_user.email %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', movie, :class => "btn btn-primary"%></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_movie_path(movie), :class => "btn btn-primary" %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', movie, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => "btn btn-primary" %></td>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</div>
```

I used a div with id `#movies_list` so that I could replace that div using js and partial.

This is my `show_category.js.erb` file:

```
$("#movies_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("show_category")) %>");
```

And this is my partial `_show_category.html.erb`:

```
<% @movies_by_category.each do |key, value| %>
<tr>&nbsp;</tr>
<tr>&nbsp;</tr>

<% if key == params[:category]%>
<th> <%= key %> <th>
  <% value.each do |movie| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= movie.title %></td>
      <td><%= movie.rating %></td>
      <% if false %>
      <td>
        <%= form_for @rating do |rating_form| %>
          <%= rating_form.number_field :rating, class: 'rating', 'data-size' => 'xs'%>
          <%= rating_form.submit 'Add', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-success' %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
      <% end %>
      <% if !current_user.nil? %>
        <% if movie.user.email == current_user.email %>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', movie, :class => "btn btn-primary"%></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_movie_path(movie), :class => "btn btn-primary" %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', movie, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => "btn btn-primary" %></td>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However my JavaScript never gets called! What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Was `show_category` action called? You can check it in a server log. Add code of the action, please

Comment: This is what I see on the Rails server console: `Started GET "/movies/show_category" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-06 12:26:29 +0530
Processing by MoviesController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"show_category"}
  Movie Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "movies".* FROM "movies" WHERE "movies"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:75
Completed 404 Not Found in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)


  
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Movie with 'id'=show_category):
  
app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:75:in 'set_movie'`

Comment: Also, since I mentioned the partial name in the link_to, I did not make a separate entry for this in `routes.rb` file. Would that be okay? or is it mandatory to make an entry there?

Comment: `link_to` is not the way to partial, you can't mention the partial in `link_to` helper. It is a way to separate controller action, which you need to implement. I sincerely advise you to go through [this ROR tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) before continue with your project.